# Gradle still builds my deleted modules in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I´m developing wear os Android app in Android Studio. I´m using gradle and I deleted 2 of my modules.

These were my steps:

1. Went to module settings and used '-' option to delete my modules
2. Then right click on module en projects left pannel and seleted Delete option to delete the directory
3. I cleaned project and Rebuild it
4. I also deleted .gradle in my projects folder and .gradle in $home/user folder
5. When I re-run my project and gradle starts from scratch downloading all dependencies and with no cache, it catchs my deleted modules directories again and they appear again with a .iml file inside

My main problem was that I was calling a Activity in one of my aperative modules but system was calling a activity from my deleted module...

I´m not sure if I´m deleting gradle modules properly or not, in order to avoid calls to unexisting classes

Comment: Try invalidating caches and restarting android studio after cleaning your project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two suggestions

- Check your settings.gradle to ensure your module isn't still
  included.
- Check your app's build.gradle to ensure it doesn't have a
  compile/implementation for the deleted module.